# Graylog - Failed to write to socket: fwrite(): send of 136 bytes failed with errno=111 Connection refused (8)

Tags: sockets, graylog2, graylog

I am getting this error when log alert with Gelf logger.

**RuntimeException**

```
Failed to write to socket: fwrite(): send of 136 bytes failed with errno=111 Connection refused (8)
```

**Code**

```
$transport = new UdpTransport("127.0.0.1", 6379, UdpTransport::CHUNK_SIZE_LAN);

$publisher = new Publisher();
$publisher->addTransport($transport);

$message = new \Gelf\Message();
$message->setShortMessage("Foobar!")
        ->setLevel(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::ALERT)
        ->setFullMessage("There was a foo in bar")
        ->setFacility("example-facility")
;

$publisher->publish($message);

$logger = new \Gelf\Logger($publisher, "example-facility");
$logger->alert("Foobaz!"); //getting error here
dd($logger);
```

And i am start redis server on this port `6379`. But don't know why i am getting fwrite issue.

Comment: Are you sure this is the real code? 'Connection refused' is a TCP error, not a UDP error, and it would happen on `connect()`, not `fwrite()`.

Comment: yes this is ryt code that i am using.

Comment: yes when i used tcp its working but don't now where my message going.

Comment: What does Redis have to do with Graylog? What GELF library are you using? What's the configuration of your Graylog inputs? Is there a firewall (packet filter) blocking access to the inputs?

Comment: Using this `https://github.com/bzikarsky/gelf-php`